# how to use filter and regexmatch to match data in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, array-formulas

[image]

so I want to match whether the data in column A contains data in column filter (B) then if yes it will produce values ​​like those in column C but when I tried I am stuck with my formula as it is in column D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try:

```
=index(if(len(A2:A),ifna(regexextract(A2:A,textjoin("|",1,B2:B))),))
```

[image]